# Spring Security Capabilities duplicate roles

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have two roles: User and Admin. 
Users can be both users and admins, and right now I have

```
<security:authorize ifAllGranted="ADMIN">
                    <li><a href="report.htm"><span>Report</span></a></li>
                    <li><img src="images/nav_div.gif" width="1" border="0"></li>
                    <li><a href="score.htm" target="_blank"><span>Score
            </span></a></li>
                    <li><img src="images/nav_div.gif" width="1" border="0"></li>
                    <li><a href="admin.htm" target="_blank"><span>Admin</span></a></li>
                    <li><img src="images/nav_div.gif" width="1" border="0"></li>
                </security:authorize>
                <security:authorize ifAllGranted="USER">
                    <li><a href="report.htm"><span>Report</span></a></li>
                    <li><img src="images/nav_div.gif" width="1" border="0"></li>

                    <li><img src="images/nav_div.gif" width="1" border="0"></li>
                    <li><a href="admin.htm" target="_blank"><span>User Settings</span></a></li>
                    <li><img src="images/nav_div.gif" width="1" border="0"></li>
                </security:authorize>
```

However, If you are both an analyst and admin, it duplicates the tabs.
I want to know how to format it so that if you are both, it overrides as admin.
Do I have to add another

Does AllGranted mean you must have those roles and nothing else?

Comment: Why not use `ifAnyGranted` instead?

Comment: because if I do if Anygranted, it duplicates the tabs because they are user and admin

Comment: Remove the duplicate `<security:authorize` section. Just use one with `IfAnyGranted` and both roles.

Comment: Admin has different specifications and titles for the tabs, if I did that, then they would both be the same

Comment: I missed that; sorry. What about using `access="hasRole('ADMIN') AND !hasRole('USER')`

Comment: Ok awesome. Can you use || in this? Could I potentially do this: <security:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN') and !hasRole('USER') || hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('USER')">

Comment: Most likely. the `access` attribute will take any spring security expression.